# c# is it possible to write to a process using the OS shell?

Tags: c#, shell

in C# you can create a new process using the ProcessStartInfo class. This class has the property UseShellExecute that must be set to false in order to redirect standard input and standard out.

If this property is set to true, then the OS shell is supposed to start the process.

This is convenient because the standard output is already being piped to the screen as I want.  Therefore I was curious as to whether it is possible to just write to the process using any other methods. If the shell is handling output to the screen, shouldn't it be possible for me to get the shell to take some input command that I desire?

I am aware that I could just redirect standard output and standard input myself, but seeing as output is already being handled fine by the shell, I keep wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to write to the process while also allowing the shell to write to the process.

This introduces lots of problems with ordering and thus is disallowed.

However you can set `UseShellExecute` to `true` but leave `RedirectStandardOutput` as `false` to avoid having to handle the output from the program. You would need to set `RedirectStandardInput` to `true` and handle piping your programs input into the program however.

Remember by doing the piping manually all synchronization problems disappear as you have the opportunity to control when the data flows through. In the simplest case of where you want to run a program, enter a little data, then let the user have control you can ensure the user doesn't accidentally impede your automation for instance.

Comment: I think that according to the documentation for "RedirectStandardInput" I cannot write to standard input for the process with UseShellExecute = true or the write will throw an exception. I assume that means I shouldn't do that.

Regardless, I think you have answered my question. It seems like I have to set UseShellExecute to false and just do everything manually myself.

I already have 3 other threads going, I really didn't want to have a thread of my own just to do some writes and reads, but I guess if I have to, I have to.